# Cannot upscale raster with rasterio

Tags: python, raster, resolution, rasterio

I am trying to upscale a raster using `rasterio` but I don't know why my process gets killed.

It can print `"i am arrived here"` but on the `reproject()` I have as terminal output:

```
killed
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
with rasterio.open(mask) as src:
    df_mask = src.read(1)
    aff_mask = src.transform
    profile_mask = src.profile
    width = src.width


profile_esm.update( compress='lzw', dtype = 'float32' )

## using reproject with the same CRS but changing the cell size

new_df= np.empty( shape = ( round(df_mask.shape[0] * 10),
                round(df_mask.shape[1] * 10 )), dtype = 'float32')

newaff = Affine(aff_mask.a / 10, aff_mask.b, aff_mask.c,
                aff_mask.d, aff_mask.e / 10, aff_mask.f)


profile_mask.update( compress='lzw', dtype = 'float32')

print("i am arrived here")
reproject(
        df_mask, new_df,
        src_transform = aff_mask,
        dst_transform = newaff,
        src_crs = src.crs,
        dst_crs = src.crs,
        resampling = Resampling.nearest)

print("i am after")
with rasterio.open('resampling_mask.tif', 'w', **profile_mask) as dst:
    reproject(
        df_mask, new_df,
        src_transform = aff_mask,
        dst_transform = newaff,
        src_crs = src.crs,
        dst_crs = src.crs,
        resampling = Resampling.nearest)

    dst.write(new_df,  indexes=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're seeing the death of your program, but the reproject function is not the way to upscale data. Instead, use the dataset's read method and specify a larger output shape:

```
with rasterio.open(mask) as dataset:
    upscaled_mask = dataset.read(1, out_shape=(dataset.height * 10, dataset.width * 10))
```

Comment: Dear @sgillies, many thanks for your reply. I tried your code but unfortunatelly it didn't work for me: no output rescaled... I used gdal.Translate() to do so.